# Registering and Deleting an Account

Tags: python, passwords, account

I hate to come with another problem on the same day, let alone two, but now I need a way to register and delete accounts. Here's the entire script:

```
accounts={'Robrajow':'password', 'Hacker':'hack', 'Noob':'lololol1'}
option1=0
option2=0
loop=1
while loop==1:
    print "Welcome to Telemology! You can login, register, delete an account, or exit."
    loginchoice = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
    if loginchoice=='login':
        choice = raw_input("What is your username? ")
        choice2 = raw_input("What is your password? ")
        if (choice in accounts):
            option1=1
        else:
            option1=0
        if (choice2 == accounts[choice]):
            option2=1
        else
            option2=0
        if option1==1 and option2==1:
            print "Welcome to Telemology,", choice
        else:
            print "The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again or register."
    elif loginchoice=='register':
        newuser=raw_input("What is your new username? ")
        if (newuser in accounts):
            newuser=raw_input("That account name is already taken. Please enter another: ")
        newpass=raw_input("What is your new password? ")
        print newuser,", welcome to Telemology!" 
        print newpass, "is your new password!"
        print "Write it down and hide it!"
    elif loginchoice=='delete':
        unsure=raw_input("Do you really want to delete your account? It will never return! ")
        if unsure=='yes':
            choice = raw_input("What is your username? ")
            choice2 = raw_input("What is your password? ")
            if choice in accounts:
                option1=1
            else:
                option1=0
            if choice2 in password:
                option2=1
            else:
                option2=0
            if option1==1 and option2==1:
                print "Goodbye forever,", choice
            else:
                print "The username or password you entered is incorrect."
        elif unsure=='no':
            print "I hoped so."
        else:
            print "Invalid input."
    elif loginchoice==exit:
        print "Goodbye!"
        loop=0
    else:
        print "What? You can only input login, delete, register, or exit."
```

Please ignore the numerous errors and complex lines of code that could be replaced with one. I only need a way to register and delete accounts (a.k.a. the dictionary entries).

On the off chance that you decide to rewrite the ENTIRE script for me, much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty complete rewrite:

```
import hashlib
import getpass

class Auth(object):
    class UserNameTakenError(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, userDict):
        self._users = {name:self.hash(pwd) for name,pwd in userDict.iteritems()}

    def hash(self, pw):
        return hashlib.sha256(pw+"&@#salt)(string)846!^").digest()

    def validate(self, name, pwd):
        return (name in self._users) and (self._users[name]==self.hash(pwd))

    def create(self, name, pwd):
        if name in self._users:
            raise Auth.UserNameTakenError()
        else:
            self._users[name] = self.hash(pwd)

    def delete(self, name, pwd):
        if self.validate(name, pwd):
            del self._users[name]

def getYes(msg):
    return raw_input(msg).lower() in ('y','yes')

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.auth = Auth({'Robrajow':'password', 'Hacker':'hack', 'Noob':'lololol1'})
        self.actions = {
            'login':    self.doLogin,
            'l':        self.doLogin,
            'register': self.doRegister,
            'r':        self.doRegister,
            'delete':   self.doDelete,
            'd':        self.doDelete,
            'exit':     self.doExit,
            'e':        self.doExit,
            'x':        self.doExit,
            'q':        self.doExit
        }

    def welcome(self):
        return raw_input("\nWelcome to Telemology! You can Login, Register, Delete an account, or Exit.\nWhat would you like to do? ")

    def doLogin(self):
        name = raw_input("What is your username? ")
        pwd = getpass.getpass("What is your password? ")
        if self.auth.validate(name, pwd):
            print "Welcome to Telemology, {0}".format(name)
        else:
            print "The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again or register."
        return False

    def doRegister(self):
        name = raw_input("What is your new username? ")
        pwd = getpass.getpass("What is your new password? ")
        try:
            self.auth.create(name, pwd)
            print "{0}, welcome to Telemology!".format(name)
        except Auth.UserNameTakenError:
            print "That account name is already taken. Please try again."
        return False

    def doDelete(self):
        name = raw_input("What is your username? ")
        pwd = getpass.getpass("What is your password? ")
        if self.auth.validate(name, pwd):
            if getYes("Do you really want to delete your account? It will never return! "):
                self.auth.delete(name, pwd)
                print "Goodbye forever, {0}".format(name)
            else:
                print "I hoped so."
        else:
            print "The username or password you entered is incorrect."
        return False

    def doExit(self):
        print "Goodbye!"
        return True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            act = self.welcome().lower()
            if act in self.actions:
                if self.actions[act]():
                    break
            else:
                print "What? You can only input login, delete, register, or exit."

def main():
    myapp = App()
    myapp.run()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time, you're a nice person =). You could use `getpass` to get the password to prevent its being echoed. And imho 'q' should be an exit option. But otherwise, nice code!

Comment: @katrielalex: good suggestions! I have modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Allowing `{}`, not just `{1}`, in `'{}'.format(x)` only works since Python 3.1.

Comment: @Hugh: interesting, I was going by the [dev docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#formatstrings) which say 3.1, the [stable docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) say 2.7. So let's say "won't work in < 2.6 or 3.0 but will work in 2.7 and 3.1".

Comment: @Chris Morgan: alright; have updated code. Should now be good for any Python >= 2.6

Comment: @Chris: the dev docs are Python 3 only, so won't mention Python 2.x at all. I got bitten by that just the other day :p.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're using a dictionary to store accounts. To add an item to a dictionary, you do:

```
accounts["newusername"] = "newpassword"
```

And to remove an item, it looks like:

```
del accounts["usernametodelete"]
```

(But I suggest you do spend some time working on your "complex lines of code that could be replaced with one"--it will make the program much easier to read. For example, where you have the complex set of if/else statements setting option1 and option2, why not just use something like:

```
if choice in accounts and choice2 == accounts[choice]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code, there are lots of errors.

I am assuming this is what you want to do.

```
>>> if username in accounts:   # if the username is in accounts
    if accounts[username] == password:  # check whether the password is same
        del accounts[username]  # if it is, delete the user
    else:
        print 'Password invalid' # else tell the user the password is invalid
```

If not, comment and I will update.